# Trying to restore Library files from backup made with Windows7

Tags: windows-7, backup, restore, libraries

I wish I knew this before I backed up my info and restored my laptop but, here I am.  I back up my info using windows backup.  I want to restore specific files, NOT ALL OF THEM, I started making my files and folders selections and I could find EVERTHING BUT 3 folders with very important information I had in LIBRARIES, and I thought their physical location was DOCUMENTS/MYDOCUMENTS/  but I cannot find them, any suggestions, please?  I already tried search and I only get to the links/paths but not to the files themselves.

Comment: If if remember right, windows backup stores the backup in .WIM format, you can use 7-zip to manually unpack the wim file to a folder of choice, then root through the files to see if they are there.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you put them directly in the library location manually the location is C:\Users*username*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows

But asides from that, Unless you told the machine to back up these files im pretty sure it will only grab the folders in the library location no single files in it. If you are able to browse the back up using the restore option in windows then check there to see if your document are there.